# Diving array into subarrays issue

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to divide an array containing many numbers into smaller arrays and I use a 2D array for that.

In the below example I have an array containing 16 elements (int[] numbers). In the code below you will see what I have made so far. splitArray is working when I want to divide it into 4 smaller arrays (int arrayAmount). I am trying to spread the array across a 2D array splittedArray.

```
private static final int NUMBER_COUNT = 16;
private static int threadAmount = 4;
private static int lowestNumber = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers = generateNumber(NUMBER_COUNT);
        System.out.println("Original array:\n" + Arrays.toString(numbers));
        int[][] splittedArray = new int[threadAmount][(numbers.length/threadAmount)];

        // Split arrays and print them
        splitArray(threadAmount, numbers, splittedArray);
        System.out.println("\nSplit arrays:\n" + Arrays.deepToString(splittedArray));
    }

private static void splitArray(int arrayAmount, int[] numbers, int[][] splittedArray) {
        int elPerSubArr = numbers.length / arrayAmount;

        int x = 0;
        int i = x;

        if (numbers.length != 0) {
            while (i < numbers.length) {
                for (int j = 0; j < elPerSubArr; j++) {
                    splittedArray[x][j] = numbers[i];
                    i++;
                }
                x++;
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("There are no elements inside this array!");
        }
    }
```

Now when I call the splitArray method with an arrayAmount and a length of numbers that's % 0 when divided by the arrayAmount it works fine. For example: 16 and 4. splitArray[0] to [3] will all contain 4 elements then in that case.

How can I modify my code so that it also works when I put 15 elements? I am obviously getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` on the line where I set a value for splittedArray[x][j] since it will always loop 4 times. I have been trying for hours now and can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delay the `int[][]` allocation until you reach the remaining elements. The last array in the result will be smaller.

Do note that you current `numbers.length / arrayAmount` expression won't calculate the correct length e.g. `3 / 2 = 1` due to integer arithmetic. You can fix it by using `Math.ceil()`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int[][] splits = splitArray(2, numbers);
    System.out.println("Split arrays: " + Arrays.deepToString(splits));
}

private static int[][] splitArray(int splitCount, int[] numbers) {
    if (numbers.length == 0) {
        return new int[0][0];
    }

    int splitLength = (int) Math.ceil((double) numbers.length / (double) splitCount);
    int[][] splits = new int[splitCount][];

    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if (k == splitLength) {
            k = 0;
            j++;
        }
        if (splits[j] == null) {
            int remainingNumbers = numbers.length - i;
            splits[j] = new int[Math.min(remainingNumbers, splitLength)];
        }
        splits[j][k++] = numbers[i];
    }
    return splits;
}
```

Will print:

```
Split arrays: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a "`if (i<numbers.length) { ...`"

e.g:

```
      for (int j = 0; j < elPerSubArr; j++) {
          if (i<numbers.length) {
                splittedArray[x][j] = numbers[i];
          } else {
                splittedArray[x][j] = 0;
          }
          i++;
      }
```

Your initialization of "splittedArray" should also consider a smaller amount of source numbers:

```
 int rows = threadAmount;
 int cols = (int)Math.ceil((double)numbers.length / (double)threadAmount);
 int[][] splittedArray
            = new int[rows][cols];
```

Complete class:

```
package de.test.lang.stackexchange;

import java.util.Arrays;

@SuppressWarnings("UseOfSystemOutOrSystemErr")
public class SplitArray {

    private static final int NUMBER_COUNT = 15;
    private static final int threadAmount = 4;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers = generateNumber(NUMBER_COUNT);
        System.out.println("Original array:\n" + Arrays.toString(numbers));
        int rows = threadAmount;
        int cols = (int) Math.ceil((double) numbers.length / (double) threadAmount);
        int[][] splittedArray = new int[rows][cols];
        // Split arrays and print them
        splitArray(numbers, splittedArray);
        System.out.println("\nSplit arrays:\n" + Arrays.deepToString(splittedArray));
    }

    private static void splitArray(int[] numbers, int[][] splittedArray) {
        int nPos = 0;
        if (numbers.length != 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < splittedArray.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < splittedArray[i].length; j++) {
                    splittedArray[i][j] = (nPos < numbers.length) ? numbers[nPos] : 0;
                    nPos++;
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("There are no elements inside this array!");
        }
    }

    private static int[] generateNumber(int arrSize) {
        int[] x = new int[arrSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 1000);
        }
        return x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried your comment before the edit and it did not work, therefore I accepted Karol Dowbecki's comment.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to check that you did not exceed the length

```
private static void splitArray(int arrayAmount, int[] numbers, int[][] splittedArray) {
    int elPerSubArr = numbers.length / arrayAmount;

    int x = 0;
    int i = x;
    int length = numbers.length;

    if (length != 0) {
        while (i < length) {
            for (int j = 0; j < elPerSubArr; j++) {
                if(i == length)
                     break;
                splittedArray[x][j] = numbers[i];
                i++;
            }
            x++;
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("There are no elements inside this array!");
    }
}
```